# Laravel 5.1 - Duplicated prefix while using route groups

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

My Route Groups names are getting the same prefix twice. Is there something wrong with this code?

```
$admin_route_group = [
    'prefix' => 'admin',
    'as' => 'admin.',
    'namespace' => 'Admin',
];

Route::group($admin_route_group, function () {
    $example_route_group = [
        'prefix' => 'example',
        'as' => 'example.',
        'namespace' => 'Example',
    ];

    Route::group($example_route_group, function () {
        Route::resource('something', 'SomethingController', [
            'only' => ['index']
        ]);
    });
});
```

`php artisan route:list` output:

```
admin.example.admin.example.something.index
```

expected output:

```
admin.example.something.index
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Route names are build using both **prefix** and **as** if they are defined. That's the reason why you're getting the same prefix.

The route name is:

```
{outerGroup.as}.{innerGroup.as}.{outerGroup.prefix}.{innerGroup.prefix}.{resourceName}.{controllerMethod}
```